# What to say when somebody says "silly me"

Tags: conversation

I wonder if there is casual reaction when somebody says "silly me"?

For example somebody forgets his phone on a table when he left a office room and realized soon he did not take his phone with him. When he turns and takes his phone  from the table, he says "silly me." How to reply in witty way, even if we do not have to..

Comment: "Silly you," perhaps, or more kindly, "What a silly billy."

Comment: @Mick I feel it would be a bit too informal..what if he is your boss?

Comment: Say nothing. If you **must** say something, how about "Oh dear!"?

Comment: @Mick anything between them ? :)

Comment: @Mick ok how about " oh Jesus Christ! you're getting old"

Comment: Remember: "It is better to keep your mouth shut and appear stupid than open it and remove all doubt." ~ Mark Twain (or possibly Abraham Lincoln)

Comment: @Mick He has a point! I'll just stick to keeping on smiling..that's the safe option

Comment: @Mick "People often misquote me on the Internet" - Albert Einstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*silly me* is an informal way to say that your inattention caused something unintended (usually minor, the "silly" part) to happen. It comments on the  person making the statement.

So if you heard your friend say:

> **Silly me**, I shouldn't be so absent minded.

any response depends on your relationship with that person, from a statement that is rude to one that is supporting.

But a response is definitely not required. If you are not on good terms with that person, it might be understood as hostile..

Regarding your boss, you might be respectful and say:

> Don't worry about it, we all can be forgetful at times.

though it might be better not to say anything if it might be used against you later.

Answer (score 4):

If a friend, then I usually say something like "Yeah, silly you" or, depending on the context, "Yeah, you're an idiot", although teasingly, not seriously.

If it's your boss (or someone who you don't want to insult) then you can say something like:

> No, not at all. It's a common mistake.
>
> No, anyone could make that mistake.
>
> Think nothing of it.
>
> Don't worry about it.

and various others.

Comment: happens, dont worry/no worries

Comment: The question asks about *silly me*, not *silly you*. "silly me" is a way to say that your inattention caused something unintended (usually minor) to happen. It only involves one person.

Comment: @user3169  I think OP is pretty clear he's asking for the *response* when someone says "silly me".  Also in comments he asks "what if it is your boss?"